# Is there anything I might want to save from the Windows.old folder if I don't want to downgrade Windows?

Tags: windows, windows.old

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently and have a windows.old folder, which I am interested in deleting because it takes up a lot of disk space. Several websites have noted that windows.old exists in case I want to recover anything from it, but they don't say what sort of things those might be.

Assuming I don't want to downgrade Windows, is there anything I might want to save from the Windows.old folder if I don't want to downgrade Windows?

Comment: If you don't want to downgrade delete the folder

Answer (score 1):

If you performed an in-place upgrade then there should be nothing in that folder that is not already in your current Windows directory.

During installation the Windows folder is copied for you to be able to downgrade, the installer then starts work upgrading the main copy. You effectively end up with two equivalent copies of your system, one with Windows 10 and one with your old OS.

If you haven't noticed anything missing then you probably never will. Just delete it.